# JavaScript Array `console.log` output behaviour

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

When we run a `forEach()` function on an array depending on the way the `index` & `items` are arranged dev tools returns different output. I'm wondering if anyone knows why this happens.

Please see the images below:

[image]

When I swap the variables over from `item, index` to `index, item` the output looks different.

[image]

I wonder what makes the variable output different and why.

Comment: Just as a note: I only see this behavior in Chrome. Firefox makes no difference between both cases. You can also shorten the example to `console.log( "a", 1 )` vs `console.log( 1, "a", )`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you puzzled by the output changing when you swap the parameters?

Comment: There is no difference. You are just printing them in the console like that.

Comment: @Candide I think this is a good question even though it might look trivial.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `forEach`. Please [edit] your question to include what `console` implementation (what JS environment) you are using. And it would help if you could post the code/output as text, not as paintings.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN documentation regarding `console.log` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

This explains that the first parameter is handled either as an object or a string. Subsequent parameters are handled as objects.

I *assume* this forces the strings, from the second parameter onward, to print with quotes.

To read more about the chrome-console, visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#consoledirobject)

Answer (score 0):

as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) says

> ```
> Syntax
> console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
> console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);
> Parameters
>
> obj1 ... objN
> A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string representations of each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and
> ```
>
> output.

and when you write consoloe.log(item,index) it first write item and then index and vice versa